# Display other fields besides just the foreign key Id in a list using Linq to sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

What is the best way to display the username instead of the Author_Id (foreign Key) when I display a list of records.  I am using Linq to Sql on this project.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>    
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Title) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Author_Id) %>
```

<% } %>

I'm wondering if I have to pass something from the controller or if I can use lambda expressions to call a particular field based on the foreign key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your FK was in place when you built your model, you should have an Author property on your model that links to the author table, then you can do Model.Author.Name.

Comment: Thanks, this was the syntax I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By this point your ViewModel should already contain the username.  You should aggregate the data in the controller when building your list of items in the model you pass to the page.